# CSS : Fill available size with a scrollable pane in a fixed size container with header and footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my scenario I have a `<div>` element with a fixed position on the window which has the following css attributes:

```
position: fixed;
height: 80%;
width: 30%;
top: 50px;
left: 0;
```

My requirements are to be able to put an header and a footer in that `<div>`, and to fill the remaining space with an element which, if needed, has a scrollbar to scroll vertically through its content.

How can I do that in a way that is compatible with Chrome, Mozilla and Internet Explorer / Edge?

Comment: check out `display:flex` and `overflow:auto;` :)

Comment: See the faq first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Secondly, look into flexbox.

Comment: I tried flexbox, but I didn't manage to get anything working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using flexbox (might not work with percentile height and fixed position):

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>A header</header>
  <div id="content">
    yo<br /> <br /><br /> yo<br /><br /> <br /><br />yo<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <br /><br /> <br />yo
  </div>
  <footer>A footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Nema problema :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow-y: auto` to show a vertical scrollbar if necessary.

```css
div{
  overflow-y: auto;/*will show vertical scrollbar if necessary*/
}
.header{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.footer{
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 5px;
   width: 30%;
   height: 10%;
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed; height: 80%; width: 30%; top: 50px; left: 0; border: 1px solid black;">
<div class="header">Header</div>
<p style="margin: 25px;"/>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```